# Can I loot a character I played with and died?

Tags: heat-signature

So, I was playing and died (damn you maneuverability), and as far as I know, my character is now dead forever. I thought the stash was shared, but it seems it is per character.

Is there any way to get the items from a dead character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the items are lost forever. If your agent dies any items he was carrying and any items in his stash are non-retrievable.

The only way to transfer items across agents is to retire and agent, you get the option to name and allow your most used weapon to be retrievable by other agents and other people on your steam friends list.

Comment: Just curious, have you ever found any of these named items?  I named a yellow shortblade after my first one, and I've seen a lot of yellow shortblades since, but none seem to have a special name.

Comment: I have never found any either. The only thing I've found was the Everything Gun, but that is kinda scripted

Comment: @Moacir Now that you mention it, I don't think I've ever seen the everything gun _outside_ of the scripted encounter.

Comment: @JMac Did you play with new characters? I think you can get it only once per character.

Comment: @Moacir Oh absolutely.  Most of my characters still die after a few missions (after being the personal missions twice, I've gotten a lot more risky with new characters).   But even the ones that last awhile seem to never encounter anything unique.  Not really a big deal, I found the everything gun to be a bit annoying anyways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66394/discussion-between-jmac-and-moacir).

Comment: _allow your most used weapon to be retrievable by other agents and other people on your steam friends list_ - this is inaccurate. It is not "retrievable" it can appear as a random drop, and people report that for some weapons passed on like this after 80+ hours to play it never dropped.